# How do I display the jsonP callback response on a vuejs component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am making a API call to another domain using js callback function included 
within a js script tag on html header. I can view the response on the network preview and response tab. How do I display this data on vuejs component?

```
    function setUniversalisElement(thing,text){
       var where=document.getElementById("Universalis_" + thing);
       if (where) where.innerHTML=text;
   };
   function universalisCallback(data){
      for (var thing in data){
        var d=data[thing];
        if (typeof d != "object"){
            setUniversalisElement(thing,d)
        }
        else {
            for (var t in d){
                var dd=d[t];
                setUniversalisElement(thing + "." + t,dd);
              }
          }
       }
    }
    !function(d,id,region,day){
    function yyyymmdd(day){
        var now=new Date();
        var delta=day==7?7-now.getDay():0;
        var when=new Date(now.getTime()+86400000*delta);
        return (1900+when.getYear())*10000+ 
 (1+when.getMonth())*100+when.getDate();
    };
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement('script');
        js.id=id;
        js.src=document.location.protocol+'//universalis.com/' + (region==""? region:region+"/") + yyyymmdd(day) + '/jsonpmass.js? callback=universalisCallback';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}
(document, 'universalis-js', "Asia.India", 1 );

This is the response on the Network preview tab:
    universalisCallback({number: 99991231, date: "Friday 31 December 9999",…});
Mass_G: {heading: "The Word was made flesh, and lived among us", source: "John 1:1-18",…}
Mass_Ps: {source: "Psalm 95(96):1-2,11-13"}
Mass_R1: {heading: "You have been anointed by the Holy One", source: "1 John 2:18-21",…}
copyright: {,…}
date: "Friday 31 December 9999"
day: "<div style="text-indent: -3em; margin-left: 3em;"><b>7th day within the octave of Christmas</b></div><div style="text-indent: -2em; margin-left: 3em;">&#160;&#160;(optional commemoration of Saint Silvester I, Pope)</div>"
number: 99991231
```

Comment: You just call the function `this.something = data.universalisCallback()`

Comment: [`vue-jsonp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-jsonp) might be worth a try.

Comment: tried that, but getting an error msg - app.js:20999 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: data is not defined"

found in

---> <MassReadings> at resources\assets\js\app\home\components\MassReadings.vue
       <App> at resources\assets\js\components\App.vue
         <Root>